# mariadb how to find longest sequence of concurrent numbers

Tags: concurrency, mariadb, numbers, sequence

I have a table describing members and when they were on runs e.g.:

```
memberid(varchar), RunNo(integer)
"1017",1868
"1017",1875
"1017",1877
"1017",1878
"1017",1879
"1017",1880
"1017",1882
"1017",1884
"1017",1885
"1017",1886
"1017",1887
"1017",1889
"1017",1894
"1017",1895
"1017",1896
"1017",1897
"1017",1902
"1017",1903
"1017",1904
"1017",1906
"1017",1907
"1017",1909
"1017",1910
"1017",1911
"1017",1929
"1017",1930
"1017",1931
"1017",1934
"1017",1935
"1079",1840
"1079",1844
"1079",1846
"1079",1847
"1079",1850
"1079",1854
"1079",1857
"1079",1859
"1079",1861
"1079",1863
"1079",1865
"1079",1866
"1079",1869
"1079",1870
"1079",1871
"1079",1872
"1079",1873
"1079",1874
"1079",1875
"1079",1876
"1079",1877
"1079",1878
"1079",1879
"1079",1880
"1079",1882
"1079",1884
"1079",1885
"1079",1886
"1079",1889
"1079",1890
"1079",1891
"1079",1893
"1079",1895
"1079",1897
"1079",1902
"1079",1903
"1079",1904
"1079",1905
"1079",1907
"1079",1908
"1079",1910
"1079",1911
"1079",1923
```

I would like to find for each memberid what is the longest consecutive sequence of run numbers for each runner and what is the latest and longest sequence  assuming there are a number of similar sequences and assuming the runnos are in date order.

For example 1017 has a maximum of 4 runs in a row and 1079 has a maximum of 12.

There should be a way of solving this but I have not been able to find a solution.

I am using MariaDB v10.4.22 on Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to SO, very good question. Now that I've answered see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: That is a very comprehensive response which works well on 3000 records (2 years of data). is it possible to show the start and last run of the longest range or at least the first or last run of the range as the rest can be worked out from the 'length' result?

Comment: yes, keeping track of the start in the CTE and using [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/) like [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zm6M2kDx) to get the maximum. Welcome to SO, glad to help. Please accept this answer, and ask new questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that can be solved with [recursive CTEs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) like below:

```
WITH RECURSIVE runlength AS
  (SELECT memberId AS id,
          RunNo + 1 AS next,
          1 AS length
   FROM members
   UNION ALL SELECT members.memberId,
                    RunNo+1,
                    length+1
   FROM members
   JOIN runlength ON members.memberId = runlength.id
   AND members.runNo = next)
SELECT id,
       max(length)
FROM runlength
GROUP BY id;
```

The anchor sets up the initial `runlength` contents to be the initial values, each of length 1 and the next value it wants to increase the sequence.

```
  SELECT memberId AS id,
          RunNo + 1 AS next,
          1 AS length
   FROM members
```

The recursive part looks for the next part of the sequence and increases the length:

```
SELECT members.memberId,
                    RunNo+1,
                    length+1
   FROM members
   JOIN runlength ON members.memberId = runlength.id
   AND members.runNo = next
```

Finally, as this will have far too many short sequences, we only want the maximum per user:

```
SELECT id,
       max(length)
FROM runlength
GROUP BY id;
```

Note: Because of the large number of generated rows this is by no means an efficient query and should only be used for small datasets.

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lnEcGzSR)