# MariaDB, merge items based on set of rules

Tags: mariadb

How to implement the following rules, `(knowing A < B < C < D)`

```
rule1      |   rule2      |  rule3
-----------|--------------|----------
 A->B      |   A->B       |  A->C      
 (B+1)->C  |   A->C       |  B->C      
 (B+1)->D  |   (B+1)->D   |  (C+1)->D
```

All of them should result in `A->D`

on this dataset:

```
 create table testing
    (
        id       int,
        start_dt date,
        stop_dt  date
    );
insert into testing
values (2, date '2010-02-14', date '2010-03-22'),  # R1
       (3, date '2010-03-23', date '2010-04-12'),  # R1
       (4, date '2010-03-23', date '2010-05-14'),  # R1
       (5, date '2010-05-15', date '2010-06-07'),  # R1
       # -> 2010-02-14 | 2010-06-07
       (6, date '2011-01-01', date '2011-02-02'),  # R2
       (7, date '2011-01-01', date '2011-03-04'),  # R2
       (8, date '2011-02-03', date '2011-04-04'),  # R2
       # -> 2011-01-01 | 2011-04-04
       (14, date '2014-05-05', date '2014-06-06'), # R3
       (15, date '2014-05-07', date '2014-06-06'), # R3
       (16, date '2014-06-07', date '2014-12-12'); # R3
       # -> 2012-05-05 | 2012-12-12
```

My current results:

| start_dt | stop_dt |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-02-14 | 2010-06-07 |
| 2011-01-01 | 2011-03-04 # should merge |
| 2011-02-03 | 2011-04-04 # with this |
| 2014-05-05 | 2014-12-12 |

My current approach:

1. If two similar start_dt exists then merge by applying `min(start_dt)`
2. If two similar stop_dt exists then merge by applying `max(stop_dt)`

However, this approach violet rule 2 (`A->B` is removed)

```
select min(start_dt)                                             as start_dt,
       case when count(*) = count(stop_dt) then max(stop_dt) end as stop_dt,
       grp
from (select start_dt,
             stop_dt,
             count(flag) over (order by start_dt, stop_dt) as grp
      from (select start_dt,
                   stop_dt,
                   IF(lag(stop_dt) over (order by start_dt,stop_dt) =
                      start_dt - interval 1 day, null, 1) as flag
            from (select start_dt,
                         max(stop_dt) as stop_dt
                  from (select min(start_dt)             as start_dt,
                               stop_dt,
                               if(stop_dt is null, 1, 0) as grp
                        from testing
                        group by stop_dt
                        order by start_dt, grp) as minAndMaxDate
                  group by start_dt, grp) as sdsd) with_flags) grouped
group by grp
order by grp, start_dt;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hunCQg_b)

I am using `10.4.12-MariaDB`

Thanks.

Comment: recommend using [recursive CTEs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) to form the sequences together and then select the longest entry by start_dt. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74577649/mariadb-how-to-find-longest-sequence-of-concurrent-numbers) might provide some hints.

Comment: Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/BotM-3yK), right results but I need more though as to if the two window functions at the end correctly reduce the result.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I din't understand what you exactly meant. Your approach solved the problem thanks